Lyzr Module not found even after installed
I have installed lyzr module in below path.
Location: c:\users\binod kumar\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages

and Python installed at location: C:\Users\Binod Kumar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1.venv

How to resolve the issue?
Error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lyzr'


Please show us the exact command you used to install the module.
